# Jquery Quoting String

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cannot seem to get the quotes around this statement right. No matter what combination I try.
I am really confused on how it should be quoted.

```
$(#imagearea).append("<img id='"+theWord.charAt(i).toUpperCase+"'.png'" src='images/'+theWord.charAt(i).toUpperCase+"'.png'/>");
```

Comment: Here's another example, not necessarily the same thing, but I thought you might get some fun out of it: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/S4ftm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it less confusing by putting it in two lines.

```
var myChar = theWord.charAt(i).toUpperCase();
$('#imagearea').append('<img id="'+myChar+'.png" src="images/'+myChar+'.png" />');
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip that will save some future headaches.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#imagearea').append("<img id='"+theWord.charAt(i).toUpperCase+".png' src='images/"+theWord.charAt(i).toUpperCase+".png' />");
```

It should append this:

```
<img id='x.png' src='images/x.png' />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#imagearea').append("<img id='"+theWord.charAt(i).toUpperCase+".png'  src='images/'"+theWord.charAt(i).toUpperCase+".png'/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#imagearea').append("<img id='"+theWord.charAt(i).toUpperCase+".png' src='images/"+theWord.charAt(i).toUpperCase+".png'/>");
```

Try this one

one main mistake is $('#imagearea'), u have missed the single quotes